# org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.core:2.22.4

Tags: wildfly

I want to switch from Wildfly 11 to Wildfly 18. Now I wanted to deploy an old deployment /ear (under Wildfly11 if possible) in Wildfly 18. This for testing reason. I get the above error message. At what point can I include the missing glassfish files? Is that even possible to deploy an old Ear 11 in Wildfly 18? Do I have to link to a specific module?

org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.core:2.22.4 in

C:..\wildfly\modules\org

Comment: Are you using Jersey?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your question . I could solve the problem. There was something missing in the C:\Mach\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\org\glassfish   .  in any way thanks .